# how to access source code of PolSARpro

Tags: open-source

I find the software PolSARpro is useful in my project.it says that this software is open-source, but how can I access to it's source code?

the website of PolSARpro:https://earth.esa.int/web/polsarpro/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the PolSARpro in your PC ,go to the directory in which it is installed,Locate "Soft" folder. In this folder the source code of every functionality is given.